# Add contact as a Homescreen shortcut for the iPhone 4S?

Tags: keyboard, contacts, iphone

Is it possible to add a contact to the homescreen as a shortcut ?? (like the Nokia and Android phones ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, it's not a feature of iOS. You need to a find (web-)app solution:

e.g.

#### [Speedtouchapp](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/speedtouchapp/id378360978?mt=8)

[image]

Comment: How safe are these apps, I just stumbled upon many others in the appstore. They state that the contact details run through their servers but none are saved in their database ... are these apps safe ?

Comment: If I were to give an answer, it would be speculation. You need to trust the developers and the ratings in the App Store. That's the best advice you can get.